# Issue with React-SpringBoot API when custom annotation-based authorization

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jsx, vite

**Issue:**
My front-end will successfully fetch a list of users when the controller method in Spring Boot has no annotation, but it fails when the controller method in spring boot has the custom annotation "@Admin". However, even when the "@Admin" annotation is present, Postman successfully fetches the user list.

**Main Question:**
If postman is working without me manually adding any authentication headers, should my front-end also be working without me adding any authentication headers to the request?

**Background:**
I am working on a group project for college. The project is a full stack application. We are using React.jsx for the front-end and Spring Boot for the back-end. I have no experience with Spring Boot, a group member strongly suggested we use it as he is familiar with it. So far, we have successfully gotten the APIs set up and working for registration and logging in. The front-end has a ContextProvider.jsx file to keep track of whether of not a user is logged in, what their username is, and what their role is. I am the only one working on the front-end, and my other group member is the only one working on the back end.

**Errors I am running into:**
Like I said, from Postman, I get no errors.
From my front-end, I get this error in my web dev console: `UserList.jsx:33 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}`. And in the Spring Boot terminal I get this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.ledgerlogic.models.User.getRole()" because "loggedInUser" is null at com.ledgerlogic.advice.AuthAspect.manager(AuthAspect.java:81)`

**Spring Boot Files:**

User.java model:

```
package com.ledgerlogic.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long   userId;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String role = "accountant";
    private String streetAddress;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
    private Date   birthDay;
    private Boolean status = false; //true = active & false = inactive
    private short  failedLoginAttempt;
    private Date   suspensionStartDate;
    private Date   suspensionEndDate;
    private Date   lastLoginDate;
    private Date   accountCreationDate = new Date();
    private String imageUrl;
    private List<String> previousPasswords = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne
    private Password password;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String role, Password password){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = generateUsername(firstName, lastName, accountCreationDate);
        this.previousPasswords.add(password.getContent());
    }

    private String generateUsername(String firstName, String lastName, Date accountCreationDate){
        String twoDigitsMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(accountCreationDate);
        String twoDigitsYear  = new SimpleDateFormat("yy").format(accountCreationDate);

        return Character.toString(firstName.charAt(0)).toLowerCase()+
                          lastName.toLowerCase()+
                          twoDigitsMonth+
                          twoDigitsYear;
    }

}
```

UserController.java: (irrelevant methods edited out)

```
package com.ledgerlogic.controllers;

import com.ledgerlogic.annotations.Admin;
import com.ledgerlogic.annotations.Authorized;
import com.ledgerlogic.annotations.Manager;
import com.ledgerlogic.models.Account;
import com.ledgerlogic.models.SecurityQuestion;
import com.ledgerlogic.models.User;
import com.ledgerlogic.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    public UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @Admin
    @GetMapping("/allUsers")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return this.userService.getAll();
    }
```

AuthController:

```
package com.ledgerlogic.controllers;

import com.ledgerlogic.dtos.LoginRequest;
import com.ledgerlogic.dtos.RegisterRequest;
import com.ledgerlogic.exceptions.InvalidCredentialsException;
import com.ledgerlogic.exceptions.InvalidPasswordException;
import com.ledgerlogic.models.Password;
import com.ledgerlogic.models.User;
import com.ledgerlogic.services.AuthService;

import com.ledgerlogic.services.EmailService;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;
    private final EmailService emailService;

    public AuthController(AuthService authService, EmailService emailService) {
        this.authService = authService;
        this.emailService = emailService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<User> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpSession session) throws InvalidCredentialsException {
        Optional<User> optional = authService.findByCredentials(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword());

        if (!optional.isPresent()) {
            throw new InvalidCredentialsException("username, password, or both not correct!");
        }

        // Logging user information using System.out.println
        User loggedInUser = optional.get();
        System.out.println("User logged in - Username: " + loggedInUser.getUsername() +
                ", Role: " + loggedInUser.getRole() +
                ", IsLoggedIn: true");

        session.setAttribute("user", loggedInUser);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(loggedInUser);
    }



    @PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> logout(HttpSession session) {
        session.removeAttribute("user");
        ResponseEntity.ok().body("User logged out successfully!");
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) throws InvalidPasswordException {
        String passwordContent = registerRequest.getPasswordContent();
        Password password = new Password(passwordContent, registerRequest.getPasswordSecurityQuestions());
        User newUser = new User(
                registerRequest.getFirstName(),
                registerRequest.getLastName(),
                registerRequest.getEmail(),
                registerRequest.getRole(),
                password);
        if(validatePassword(passwordContent)){
//            emailService.sendApprovalRequestEmail("abderrahimbahia19@gmail.com", created.getEmail());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(authService.register(newUser));
        }else{
            throw new InvalidPasswordException("invalid password format");
        }
    }

    public boolean validatePassword(String password){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

AuthService:

```
package com.ledgerlogic.services;

import com.ledgerlogic.models.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class AuthService {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final PasswordService passwordService;

    public AuthService(UserService userService, PasswordService passwordService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.passwordService = passwordService;
    }

    public Optional<User> findByCredentials(String username, String password) {
        return userService.findByCredentials(username, password);
    }

    public User register(User user) {
        Optional<User> existingUser = userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if(existingUser.isPresent()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User " + existingUser.get().getFirstName() + " " + existingUser.get().getLastName()+ " already exist");
        }
        this.passwordService.addNewPassword(user.getPassword());
        return userService.save(user);
    }

}
```

AuthRestriction.java annotation:

```
package com.ledgerlogic.annotations;

public enum AuthRestriction {
    LoggedIn,
    Manager,
    Admin

}
```

Authorized.java annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Authorized {

    public AuthRestriction value() default AuthRestriction.LoggedIn;
}
```

Admin.java annotation:

```
package com.ledgerlogic.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Admin {

    public AuthRestriction value() default AuthRestriction.Admin;
}
```

React Files:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

App.jsx:

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  NavLink,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar/NavBar";
import ContextProvider from "../context/ContextProvider";
import { AuthProvider } from "../context/AuthContext";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import Login from "./pages/Login/Login";
import CreateNewUser from "./pages/CreateNewUser/CreateNewUser";
import AdminDashboard from "./pages/AdminDashboard/AdminDashboard";
import UserDashboard from "./pages/UserDashboard/UserDashboard";
import ForgotPassword from "./pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword";
import ManagerDashboard from "./pages/ManagerDashboard/ManagerDashboard";
import UserList from "./pages/AdminDashboard/UserList";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound/NotFound";
import EnterNewPassword from "./pages/ForgotPassword/EnterNewPassword";
import ManagerLogin from "./pages/ManagerLogin/ManagerLogin";
import LoginChoice from "./pages/LoginChoice/LoginChoice";
import React from "react";
import UserLogin from "./pages/UserLogin/UserLogin";
import AdminLogin from "./pages/AdminLogin/AdminLogin";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isLoggedIn: false,
    username: "",
    role: "",
  });

  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <NavBar />
          <div className="pd-hz ht-100 pd-vt bg-light-gray">
            <Routes>
              {/* Login options */}
              <Route path="/" element={<LoginChoice />} />
              <Route path="/login-choice" element={<LoginChoice />} />
              <Route path="/user-login" element={<UserLogin />} />
              <Route path="/manager-login" element={<ManagerLogin />} />
              <Route path="/admin-login" element={<AdminLogin />} />

              <Route path="/create-new-user" element={<CreateNewUser />} />

              {/* Forgot password pages */}
              <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
              <Route
                path="/enter-new-password"
                element={<EnterNewPassword />}
              />

              {/* Dashboard pages */}
              <Route path="/user-dashboard" element={<UserDashboard />} />
              <Route path="/manager-dashboard" element={<ManagerDashboard />} />
              <Route
                path="/admin-dashboard"
                element={<AdminDashboard username={state.username} />}
              />

              {/* User list page */}
              <Route path="/user-list" element={<UserList />} />

              <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AppContext.jsx:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const AppContext = createContext(null)
export default AppContext
```

ContextProvider.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AppContext from "./AppContext";

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isLoggedIn: false,
    username: "",
    role: "",
  });
  const contextValue = {
    state,
    setState,
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContextProvider;
```

AdminLogin.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import logo from "../../assets/logo.png";
import styles from "./AdminLogin.module.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import * as userService from "../../services/AuthService";
import AppContext from "../../../context/AppContext";

const AdminLogin = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { state, setState } = useContext(AppContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await userService.loginUser(username, password);

      if (!user) {
        console.error("Login failed: User data not found in the response");
        // Handle the case where the response does not contain the expected user data
        return;
      }

      console.log("Login successful:", user);

      setState({
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: true,
        username: user.username,
        role: user.role,
      });

      // handle successful login based on the user role.
      if (user.role === "admin") {
        navigate("/admin-dashboard");
      } else if (user.role === "manager") {
        navigate("/manager-dashboard");
      } else {
        navigate("/user-dashboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        "Login failed:",
        error.response ? error.response.data : error.message
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
      {/* edited out for simplicity */}
            <h1 className={styles.header}>Admin Login</h1>
            <div>
              <label>
                <p>Username</p>
                <input
                  className={styles.inputBox}
                  type="text"
                  value={username}
                  onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>
                <p>Password</p>
                <input
                  className={styles.inputBox}
                  type="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />
              </label>
            </div>

            <div>
              <Link className={styles.fixLinks} to="/manager-dashboard">
                <button
                  className={styles.button}
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={handleLogin}
                >
                  Login
                </button>
              </Link>
            </div>
            ...
  );
};

export default AdminLogin;
```

UserList.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { fetchUsers } from "../../services/UserService";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./AdminDashboard.module.css";
import AppContext from "../../../context/AppContext";
import {
  activateUser,
  deactivateUser,
  suspendUser,
} from "../../services/UserService";
import { Modal, Button, Form, Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
// import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const UserList = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(AppContext);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
  const [suspensionStartDate, setSuspensionStartDate] = useState(null);
  const [suspensionEndDate, setSuspensionEndDate] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [modalMessage, setModalMessage] = useState("");
  const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.isLoggedIn && state.role === "admin") {
      fetchUsers()
        .then((response) => {
          setUsers(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Error fetching data. isLoggedIn may be false or the role may not be admin."
      );
    }
  }, [state.isLoggedIn, state.role]);

other stuff here, removed for simplicity

  return (
    <Container className={styles.dashboardContainer}>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <div className="container">
            {/* ===============
                USER LIST TABLE
                =============== */}
            <h2 className="text-center">User List</h2>
            <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>User Id</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>Role</th>
                  <th>Username</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {users.map((user) => (
                  <tr key={user.userId}>
                    <td>{user.userId}</td>
                    <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                    <td>{user.lastName}</td>
                    <td>{user.role}</td>
                    <td>{user.username}</td>
                    <td>{user.email}</td>
                    <td>{user.status ? "Active" : "Inactive"}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>

           
            <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleCloseModal}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{modalTitle}</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>{modalMessage}</Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCloseModal}>
                  Close
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>

            <hr className="my-4" />

            <h4>Contact User</h4>

            <Row>
              <Col className="col-md-2">
                <Form.Group controlId="email">
                  <Form.Label>User Email Address</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="JohnSmith@email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    className="custom-textbox"
                  />
                </Form.Group>
              </Col>
              <Col className="col-md-8">
                <p>Enter your email below:</p>
                <label>
                  <textarea
                    name="emailContent"
                    defaultValue=""
                    rows={4}
                    cols={80}
                    align="left"
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
                      color: "black",
                      borderRadius: "5px",
                    }}
                  />
                </label>
              </Col>
            </Row>

            <Row>
              <p></p>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Button
                  variant="primary"
                  onClick={() => handleButtonClick("SendEmailToUser")}
                >
                  Send Email to User
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>

            <div style={{ height: "200px" }}></div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default UserList;
```

AuthService.js:

```
import axios from "axios";


const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/auth";


export const registerUser = (userData) => {
  return axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/register`, {
    firstName: userData.firstName,
    lastName: userData.lastName,
    email: userData.email,
    passwordContent: userData.passwordContent,
    role: userData.role,
    streetAddress: userData.streetAddress,
    status: userData.status,
    passwordSecurityQuestions: userData.passwordSecurityQuestions,
  });
};


export const forgotPassword = (userData) => {
    return axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/forgotPassword`, userData);
};


export const loginUser = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, { username, password });
    console.log("Login successful:", response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Login failed:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

UserService.js: (This is where the getAllUsers request is made)

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/users";

export const fetchUsers = () => {
    return axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/allUsers`);
};

export const loginUser = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/login", { username, password });
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export const activateUser = (userId) => {
  return axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/activate/${userId}`);
};

export const deactivateUser = (userId) => {
  return axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/deactivate/${userId}`);
};

export const suspendUser = (userId, suspensionStartDate, suspensionEndDate) => {
  return axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/suspend/${userId}`);
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ledger-logic-frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "postgresql": "^0.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.1",
    "react-cookie": "^7.0.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^5.26.2",
    "reactstrap": "^9.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

I have gone through my code several times and can't find what the issue is unless I need to add an authorization token that postman adds by default or something like that. I tried giving all my code to Chat Gippity for context and asking questions and it has been no help per usual but I appreciate it trying. I've tried finding videos and tutorials online but I haven't found anything that seems applicable to this specific circumstance where it won't work with the custom annotation. My group member says that if it works in postman, it should work in react too, but I feel like react isn't doing something that postman is.